# Interpretation of changing the inputs of the partial differentation of a function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let's say I have a function like this:

$$y=\frac{a(1-b/c)}{d-b}$$

and take the partial derivative w.r.t $c$ to get:

$$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial c} = \frac{a*b/c^2}{d-b} $$

What's the interpretation if I increase $c$? Is $y$ increasing or decreasing w.r.t $c$?

Now I take the partial derviative w.r.t $b$ to get:
$$ \frac{\partial y}{\partial b} = \frac{a*(1-d/c)}{(d-b)^2} $$

What's the interpretation if I increase $b$? Is $y$ increasing or decreasing w.r.t $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{\partial y}{\partial c} = \frac{ab}{d-b} \times \frac{1}{c^2}.
$$
Hence, if $ab/(d-b) < 0$ then increasing $c$ decreases $1/c^2$ which increases $y$.

Alternatively, if $ab/(d-b) > 0$, then increasing $c$ decreases $1/c^2$ which decreases $y$.

Finally, if $a=0$ or $b=0$, then changing $c$ has no effect on $y$ whatsoever.

Can you yourself do the analysis of sensitivity to $b$?

Comment: Thank you. I got it now! I had the same initial thoughts, but I am not sure if it was correct of how I interpreted it.